# Windows 7 bluescreens every time I try to open a recent file

Tags: windows-7, bsod, taskbar

This is a computer I received today in a professional environment. I'm not sure what it was used for previously or how it was installed. I've got full local admin rights. It's currently set up with Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1 and I've installed all Windows updates. It seems stable overall, though I haven't had much time to play with it.

However there is this problem: I get a blue screen of death with the error code `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION` whenever I try to use the taskbar menu for a pinned program. It is a 100% consistent, happening every time I try, regardless of the program or action—trying to open a recent file and trying to create a new one (e.g. right-clicking the sticky-note icon and clicking *new task*) have both resulted in the bluescreen.

I've even tried it with a new user profile—the result is the same.

Comment: Did you try the things proposed [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2028871/system-service-exception-blue-screen.html)?

Comment: share the dmp file from **C:\Windows\Minidump**

Answer (score 0):

After applying few more updates (not sure why windows update didn't get them all in the first place) and also after applying hotfix for KB2731284 the problem disappeared. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error again, it would be good if with a memory installed with windows 7 you would do a windows reviction and repair since this error is usually a malfunction of the operating system, I would also recommend you since the computer has presented these errors before your middle name is backup make a backup of everything as constant as possible